# wordpress create user from facebook login plugin

Tags: wordpress, facebook-login

How do I call this function from my wordpress theme. It is supposed to be called when the one who comments logs in via facebook login function.

```
function myfb_do_login() {
global $wpdb;

// cookie
$cookie = get_facebook_cookie();
// get user data
 $fbuser = get_facebook_user($cookie);
 $username = sanitize_user($fbuser->first_name);

// put everything in nice array
$userdata = array(
  'user_pass'       =>  wp_generate_password(),
  'user_login'  =>  $username,
  'user_nicename'   =>  $username,
  'user_email'  =>  $fbuser->email,
  'display_name'    =>  $fbuser->name,
  'nickname'        =>  $username,
  'first_name'  =>  $fbuser->first_name,
  'last_name'       =>  $fbuser->last_name,
  'role'            =>  'subscriber'
);

// create new user
$new_user = wp_insert_user($userdata);

// set the auth cookie to current user id
wp_set_auth_cookie($new_user, true);

// log the user in
wp_set_current_user($new_user);

// do redirect  here
wp_safe_redirect(get_permalink(). '#response');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have user info at hand, create an array of user data an pass it to `wp_insert_user`, what userdata should contains refers to [`wp_insert_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user)<sup>codex</sup>.

code example:

```
//insert new user to db
$wpuid=wp_insert_user($userdata);
//set the auth cookie to current user id
wp_set_auth_cookie($wpuid,true);
//log the user in
wp_set_current_user($wpuid);
//do redirect  here....
wp_safe_redirect($location);
```

Comment: And how do I add the action, add_action or do_action how ?? First click on facebook login button, then after facebook login I will be redirected from facebook to same page. So where do I call the action

Comment: no actions are needed, just continue the code from $new_user = wp_insert_user($userdata) to what I provide above.

Comment: I have updated the function above. Nothing is happening. I need to do_action or something no...